# Continous orthonormal basis on a line

Tags: geometry, continuity

I'm reading RKHS of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.0952v2.pdf), but i don't understand why there is no continuous map from the line $L(\theta)$ to an ortonormal basis vector $v(\theta)\in L(\theta)$ (page 6), the hint says to use Borsuk-Ulam Theorem that says the following

> **Borsuk–Ulam theorem**
>   If $f:\mathbb{S}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is continuous then there exists an $x\in \mathbb{S}^{n}$ such that $f(-x)=f(x)$.

If I try to solve for the absurd then it is continuous, but I am not sure to use this theorem because there the starting point is $\mathbb{S}^{n}$ and in my hypothesis it is the line $L(\theta)$, or I think I'm getting it wrong.
Any proof or idea or an article that goes from finite rkhs to generalize, please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints :**

The Borsuk-Ulam theorem states a result for a continuous map on $\mathbb{S}^2$. Your line $L(\theta)$ is defined by the point $(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta))$ which is a point of $\mathbb{S}^2$.

Draw the unit circle. At each point of this circle you can associate an orthonormal basis vector $v(\theta)$. This vector should be the same that the one of the point $\theta+\pi$ (opposite to $\theta$). Therefore one of this vector points inside the circle and the other one outside the circle. Since the map is continuous and all the vectors have norm $1$ you reach a contradiction.

Comment: That point is in $\mathbb{S}^{1}$ right? and goes to an orthonormal base in $\mathbb{R}$, which can be $(cos(\theta),sin(\theta))$ divided by its norm or another could it be?